How do i increase the size of the carousel taken from the flowbit-svelte components?
I am currently working a project which requires a Carousel, so i integrated the flowbit-svelte in my svelte project. The carousel is working fine but i want to increase the size of the component,its cutting my images short and is fixed to a certain size, i have read the flowbit-svelte carousel documentation and was unable too find the solution, Please help me
<script>
    import { Carousel } from 'flowbite-svelte';
    import { scale } from 'svelte/transition';
    import { quintOut } from 'svelte/easing';

    const scaleAnimation = (x) => scale(x, { duration: 500, easing: quintOut });

    export let images = [];
</script>

<div class="carousel-container aspect-4/3 sm-h-full w-3/4 object-cover sm:w-full">
    <Carousel {images} transition={scaleAnimation} duration="7000" let:Controls let:Indicators>
        <Controls />
        <Indicators />
    </Carousel>
</div>

<style>
</style>

This is my code and:
the size of carousel at 100% browser window size is:

the size of carousel at 200% browser window size is:

I want the 200% size to be displayed at 100% browser window size, Please Help
I am expecting there would a change in the tailwind css property to pass that will change the carousel to show the entire image size

Try using inline style for the height at the carousel Component like this
added inline style at the carousel component
